# Python module wx dont play audio sounds

Tags: python, audio, module, wxwidgets

In my program, I try to randomly play some sounds. But the problem is, that I can't hear them. I get no error or something like that, I just cannot hear the sounds. Thanks for the help. Sorry if my English is bad. Also here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random
import wx

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.state("zoomed")

        container= tk.Frame(self)
        container.config()
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames={}
        for F in (fenster, fensta):
            frame= F(container, self)
            self.frames[F]=frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            frame.pack_propagate(0)

        self.show_frame(fenster)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame=self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class fenster(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        button=tk.Button(self, text="Start",
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(fensta))
        button.pack()

class fensta(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        def ok():
            def do_a():
                def __init__(self, parent):
                    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
                    self.test = wx.Sound('ja.wav')
                    self.test.Play(wx.SOUND_SYNC)

                print("a")

            def do_b():
                def __init__(self, parent):
                    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
                    self.testa = wx.Sound('nein.wav')
                    self.testa.Play(wx.SOUND_SYNC)

                print("b")

            a=random.randint(1,2)

            if a==1:
                do_a()
            elif a==2:
                do_b()

        button=tk.Button(self, text="press",  command=ok)
        button.pack()

if __name__== "__main__":
    app=SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: what platform are you using?

Comment: @DizietAsahi I am using python IDLE 2.7

Comment: Windows? OSX? Linux? How did you install wxpython?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix wxPython and Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

to test whether you have a problem with wxPython itself, use [the sound sample code](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/page_samples.html#page_samples_sound) that should have been installed on your system with wxpython.

If you cannot get sound with the sample code, then you have an issue with wxpython. There are some issues on some linux distributions and [you need to recompile it by hand while enabling sound support to get sound output](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wxpython-users/wK_U8yWkUcc/rjuGyHetGcoJ)

If the sound sample works just fine, then your problem might be due to the fact that you are mixing tk and wx in the same program. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I think you are right. The Problem seems to be that I am mixing tk and wx. When I try to play the sound only in wx it works, but when I try to build the GUI with Tkinter it doesn't work. Thanks for the help anyway.